# What influence has an object which only uses Actions in Xtext on the concrete and abstract syntax?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, xtext

I am currently looking into the Xtext source code of someone else. There is an object, which only uses Actions and nothing else. Let the object's name be "*Empty*". The relevant parts of the source code are below.

```
    grammar ...
    import "myUri" as MyImport
    ...
    SomeOtherObject returns MyImport::SomeOtherObject:
        "someKeyword" AnotherObject empty += Empty
    ;
    // The most relevant part:
    Empty returns MyImport::Empty:
        {MyImport::Empty}
    ;
    ...
```

I am wondering if this object has any influence on the concrete syntax? Furthermore, how does the Empty Object look like? Because of the line `empty += Empty`, there could be multiple instances of Empty, but I wonder how the parser decides how many instances are created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+=` is not for the parser. It is for the metamodel inference. So `empty` will be a list. `empty+=Empty+` or `empty+=Empty+` will lead to errors when running the workflow

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After parsing a model will the list "empty" have any instance? Or are the instances created by some other code, which is not related to the parser?

Comment: the parser will create it.